# Lucene Syntax on ELK 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to find a way to parse UserAgent on kibana 5.3 so I could get the following response:

```
"aws-sdk-java/1.11.76 Mac_OS_X/10.12.5"
"aws-sdk-java/1.11.78 Mac_OS_X/10.11.2"
"aws-sdk-java/1.11.80 Mac_OS_X/10.10.1"
"aws-sdk-java/1.11.83 Mac_OS_X/10.12.2"
"aws-sdk-java/1.10.33 Mac_OS_X/10.12.3"
```

etc..

I tried with ? to replace numbers

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "userAgent": {
        "query": "aws-sdk-java/?.??.?? Mac_OS_X/??.??.??",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or <0-100> for number ranges

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "userAgent": {
        "query": "aws-sdk-java/<0-100>.<0-100>.<0-100> Mac_OS_X/<0-100>.<0-100>.<0-100>",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or even with *

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "userAgent": {
        "query": "aws-sdk-java/*.*.* Mac_OS_X/*.*.*",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing, Kibana never find anything, I need to do :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "userAgent": {
        "query": "aws-sdk-java/*",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then it works, but i don't want to have to exclude the rest of the string.

the field userAgent is of type string, he is **Searchable** and **Analyzed**. Can anyone could give me a hint on what i'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `keyword` type of sub-field for your `userAgent` field. Or, if you relied on Elasticsearch to map your string field [it should have it by default](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings).

After you add this `keyword` field, for example like this:

```
{
  "userAgent": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "userAgent.keyword": "aws-sdk-java/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2} Mac_OS_X/[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]+"
    }
  }
}
```